# How to correctly realize login via Facebook in react

Tags: reactjs, frontend, facebook-login

I want to realize login via Facebook, I have an icon of Facebook and when user will click on it he must see window from Facebook.

I try used FacebookLoginWithButton and FacebookLogin but I can't it combine with icon.

**Icon:**

```py
<a href="#" className="fb">
    <img className="icon-style"/>
</a>
```

```css
.icon-style {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 5px 10px;
}
.fb img {
    content: url('/static/imgs/fb.svg');
}
```

```html
<FacebookLogin
    className="myButton"
    appId="some id"
    autoLoad={false}
    fields="name,email"
    callback={this.responseFacebook}
/>
```